# get the values of array which is nested in json and display the array elements by each id -react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects like this.

```
var matchingJobs = [
        {
            jobCode: "J-1234",
            jobType: "Basic",
            Country: "US",
            locations: ["7300", "1700", "1000"]
        },
        {
            jobCode: "J-2232",
            jobType: "Travel",
            Country: "CA",
            locations: ["7300", "1700"]
        },
        {
            jobCode: "J-7002",
            jobType: "Basic",
            Country: "AU",
            locations: ["7300", "1000"]
        },
        {
            jobCode: "J-6749",
            jobType: "Travel",
            Country: "US",
            locations: ["7300", "1700", "1000"]
        }
    ];
```

I want to display the locations elements by each jobcode. here i am trying to render the element and return the array data but i am getting error. How to display locations array elements for each job code.

**render**

```
render() {
  const { matchingJobs } = this.props;

  return (
    <div className ="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 jobSearchName jobSearchColumn">
      <div className="configLocationList">
         <h6>{matchingJobs.map((info,i)=><span key={i}>({info.locations.map((obj,index)=><span key={index}>{obj}</span>)})</span>)}</h6></div></div>
  )
}
```

How to map inside a map function please let me know this.

Comment: *"i have a Json like this"* That's not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Spaces in code aren't the enemy. :-) They really help readability.

Comment: "*but i am getting error*" – Sharing the error would be helpful.

Comment: You haven't closed the `div`s.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  it is displaying all the locations values for each iteration. I need to display for first first job code 3 locations and so on

Comment: @user7411584 You can check my Answer. Hope this will help you. I have also attached demo for you.

Comment: @user7411584, i have posted sample solution please check that i think it will help

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the `render` method to display records.

```
render() {
    const { matchingJobs } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className ="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 jobSearchName jobSearchColumn">
        <div className="configLocationList">
          {matchingJobs.map((info,i)=>
          <div key={i} style={{margin: 10}}>
            Job Code: {info.jobCode}<br/>
            Location: ({info.locations.join(", ")})
          </div>)}         
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I have used `join` method to display location with comma separate.

Here is the working demo for you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j5pzn3

**Your page will be display as below.**
[image]

Comment: Please keep working demos **on site**, rather than putting them off-site, by using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: it is displaying all the locations array for each job code. coming like this (7300,1700,1000),(7300,1700) .... like this

Answer (score 0):

```
    const { matchingJobs } = this.state;

    return (

       <div className="configLocationList">

           {matchingJobs.map((info,i)=>{

           return (

           <span key={i}>
               Job Code : {info.jobCode}
               <br />
               {info.locations.map((obj,index)=>{
               return (

               <div key={index}>
                   Locations {obj}
               </div>
               )
               })}
               <br />
               <br />
               <br />
           </span>

           )
           })
           }
       </div>

      )
    };
```

Outputs : -

```
Job Code : J-1234
Locations 7300
Locations 1700
Locations 1000



Job Code : J-2232
Locations 7300
Locations 1700



Job Code : J-7002
Locations 7300
Locations 1000



Job Code : J-6749
Locations 7300
Locations 1700
Locations 1000
```

Comment: it is returning all the locations array for each iteration . It is coming like this - 73001700100073001700 ... like this

Comment: @user7411584, yeah that's what you wanted right?. if you don't want to iterate inner locations then remove inner loop for locations.

Comment: I want to display like this - 1st job  - 7300 1700 1000 then 2nd job 7300 1700 like this ...but now it is coming entire locations array for 1st job (7300 1700 1000 7300 1700 .... so on ) all objects locations

Comment: @user7411584, check that same output is there i think. country wise i showed there for sample.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the solution for which you may be looking for

```
  const { matchingJobs } = this.props;

  return (
    <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 jobSearchName jobSearchColumn">
        <div className="configLocationList">
            <h6>
                matchingJobs.map((info,i)=>
                {
                <React.Fragment>
                    <span key={i}> info.jobCode</span>
                </React.Fragment>
                <React.Fragment>
                    obj.locations.map((obj, index)=>
                    {
                    <span key={i}>obj</span>
                    })
                </React.Fragment>
                });
            </h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
  };
```